# How to avoid commas for a specific column in csv file

Tags: talend

I have similar question in input csv file. I’m currently loading data from csv file to DB. Getting wrong data in target table not sure how to ignore commas

I have below input

```
Col1,col2,col3
1,2,3,4
```

Output should be populated as

```
Col1 col2  col3   col4
1       2  3 ,4
```

3,4 should be  populated in col3

Instead I’m getting data like below. It has not populated  like above. Can someone please help me.Not sure how to do it in Talend.

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4
1       2     3      4
```

3,4 data was not populating in same column not sure how to ignore ,comma for 3 and 4

Comment: the easiest way to fix it is to fix the CSV file. It a field contains a comma it should be quoted (",")

Comment: as neuhaus stated, you will need to have some escape character, because as the name `Comma-separated-values` (CSV) states, the values are spearated by a comma which means that **every** comma is takes as separator

Comment: Note that escape characters can occur in a column as well and would then be escaped too (e.g. `"some ""quoted"" text"`). Handling those cases can be quite cumbersome so you're better off using one of the existing CSV libraries like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Text enclosure character in source file

```
Col1,col2,col3
"1","2","3,4"
```

You may also use different escape characters or even delimiter. see "CSV Options" in Component tFileInputDelimited